# Does there exist $C>0$ such that $\max \{|a_1|, |a_1+a_2|\} \leq C \cdot \max \{|b_1|, |b_1+b_2|\}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

Does there exist some $C>0$ such that
$$
\max \{|a_1|, |a_1+a_2|\} \leq C \cdot \max \{|b_1|, |b_1+b_2|\}?
$$
whenever $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ are complex numbers such that $|a_k| \leq |b_k|$, $k=1,2$ ($C$ needs to be independent of the choice of such numbers).

If
$$
\max \{|a_1|, |a_1+a_2|\} = |a_1|
$$
then clearly
$$
|a_1| \leq |b_1| \leq 1 \cdot \max \{|b_1|, |b_1+b_2|\}.
$$
What can be done in the case when
$\max \{|a_1|, |a_1+a_2|\} = |a_1+a_2|$?
We have
$$
|a_1+a_2| \leq |a_1|+|a_2| \leq |b_1|+|b_2| \leq \ldots
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

$$\left|b_2\right| = \left|b_2 + b_1 - b_1\right| \le \left|b_1+b_2\right| + \left|b_1\right|$$

So $$\left|a_1 + a_2\right| \le 2 \left|b_1\right| + \left|b_1 + b_2\right| \le 3 \max\{\left|b_1\right|, \left|b_1 + b_2\right|\}$$

Comment: Kroki, you could write in your answer that $C$ cannot be less than $3$, indeed if $a_1=i$, $a_2=2i$, $b_1=i$, $b_2=-2i$, it results that $|a_1|\leqslant|b_1|\,$ and $\,|a_2|\leqslant|b_2|$, moreover, $C=C\cdot\max\{|b_1|, |b_1+b_2|\}\geqslant\max\{|a_1|,|a_1+a_2|\}=3$.